# "Map Reduce" reduce function finds value undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I have the following collection:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "cust_id" : "abc123",
  "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
  "status" : "A",
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : [{
      "sku" : "ggg",
      "qty" : 7,
      "price" : 2.5
    }, {
      "sku" : "ppp",
      "qty" : 5,
      "price" : 2.5
    }]
}
```

My map function is:

```
 var map=function(){emit(this._id,this);}
```

For debugging purpose I overide the emit method as follows:

```
var emit = function (key,value){
  print("emit");
  print("key: " + key + "value: " + tojson(value));
  reduceFunc2(key, toJson(value));
}
```

and the reduce function as follows:

```
var reduceFunc2 = function reduce(key,values){
  var val = values;
  print("val",val);
  var items = [];
  val.items.some(function (entry){
    print("entry is:::"+entry);
    if (entry.qty>5 && entry.sku=='ggg'){
      items.push(entry)
    }
  });
  val.items = items;
  return val;
}
```

But when I apply map as:

```
var myDoc = db.orders.findOne({
  _id: ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351")
});
map.apply(myDoc);
```

I get the following error:

```
emit key: 51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351 value:
{
  "_id":" ObjectId(\"51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351\")",
  "cust_id":"abc123",
  "ord_date":" ISODate(\"2012-10-03T18:30:00Z\")",
  "status":"A",
  "price":25,
  "items":[
    {
       "sku":"ggg",
       "qty":7,
       "price":2.5
    },
    {
       "sku":"ppp",
       "qty":5,
       "price":2.5
    }
  ]
}

value:: undefined
Tue Jul 30 12:49:22.920 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Cannot call method 'some' of undefined
```

you can find that their is an items field in the value as printed which is of array kind, even then it is throwing error cannot call some on undefined, if someone can tell where i am going wrong.

Comment: What you're doing is not `MapReduce`. You're just calling your own `map` function on a document.

Comment: @ Leonid Beschastny I know, but even on doing map reduce I am not getting result so i am trying to debug it by calling reduce from map.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your `reduceFunc2` function:

```
var reduceFunc2 = function reduce(key,values){
  var val = values[0]; //values is an array!!!
  // ...
}
```

Reduce function meant to reduce an array of elements, emitted with the same `key`, to a single document. So, it accepts an array. You're emitting each key only once, so it's an array with a single element with it.

Now you'll be able to [call your `MapReduce` normally](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/):

```
db.orders.mapReduce(map, reduceFunc2, {out: {inline: 1}});
```

The way you overridden `emit` function is broken, so you shouldn't use it.

**Update**. Mongo may skip reduce operation if there is only one document associated with the given key, because there is no point in reducing a single document.

The idea of `MapReduce` is that you maps each document into an array of key-value pairs to be reduced on the next step. If there is more than one value associated with the given key, `Mongo` runs a `reduce` operation to reduce it to the single document. Mongo expects `reduce` function to return reduced document in the same format as the elements which was emitted. It's why Mongo may run `reduce` operation any number of times for each key (up to the number of `emits`). There is also no guarantee that `reduce` operation will be called at all if there is nothing to reduce (e.g. if there is only one element).

So, it's best to move `map` logic to the proper place.

**Update 2.** Anyway, why are you using `MapReduce` here? You can just query for the documents you need:

```
db.orders.find({}, {
  items: {
    $elemMatch: {
      qty: {$gt: 5},
      sku: 'qqq'
    }
  }
})
```

**Update 3.** If you really want to do it with `MapReduce`, try this:

```
db.runCommand({
  mapreduce: 'orders',
  query: {
    items: {
      $elemMatch: {
        qty: {$gt: 5},
        sku: 'ggg'
      }
    }
  },
  map: function map (){
    this.items = this.items.filter(function (entry) {
      return (entry.qty>5 && entry.sku=='ggg')
    });
    emit(this._id,this);
  },
  reduce: function reduce (key, values) {
    return values[0];
  },
  verbose: true,
  out: {
    merge: 'map_reduce'
  }
})
```

Comment: it gives only "{" on doing values[0]

Comment: I get the following result:

Comment: {
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "value" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
    "cust_id" : "abc123",
    "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
    "status" : "A",
    "price" : 25,
    "items" : [{
        "sku" : "ggg",
        "qty" : 7,
        "price" : 2.5
      }, {
        "sku" : "ppp",
        "qty" : 5,
        "price" : 2.5
      }]
  }
} I am getting the following result,whereas items should have only one object as per the reduce logic.

Comment: It shows clearly it does not use reduce:        ],
        "timeMillis" : 1,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 3,
                "emit" : 3,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 3
        },
        "ok" : 1,
}

Comment: I am going MR as I have to query multiple collection and than club the result and return to user.

Comment: But you neither maps your data, nor reduces it, you only projects it. Why can't you simply join the results of multiple queries?

Comment: this is what I am doing:jing.$cmd { "mapreduce" : "orders" , "map" : "function map(){emit(this._id,this);}" , "reduce" : "function reduce(key,values){for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){var val=values[i];var items=[];val.items.some(function(entry){if (entry.qty>5&&entry.sku=='ggg'){items.push(entry)}});val.items=items;};return values;}" , "verbose" : true , "out" : { "merge" : "map_reduce"} , "query" : { "$where" : "return this.items.some(function(entry){return entry.qty>5})&&this.items.some(function(entry){return entry.sku=='ggg'})"}}, map & reduce fnctnare gtng crtd dynmicly based on usr requir

Comment: `$where` is slow, it's best to avoid it where possible. See my update.

Comment: Even with the above approach the problem exists. so when I am querying  the collection it is picking the right document, but in the sub document "items" even other object which do not match criteria exists.like    {
       "sku":"ppp",
       "qty":5,
       "price":2.5
    }

Comment: Sorry, I missed `this.items = ` in my example. Try updated version.

Comment: {
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "value" : [{
      "sku" : "ggg",
      "qty" : 7,
      "price" : 2.5
    }, {
      "sku" : "ppp",
      "qty" : 5,
      "price" : 2.5
    }]
}

Comment: Just tried it myself and it worked fine. Are you sure that you tried the last version of my code>

Comment: {
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "value" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
    "cust_id" : "abc123",
    "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
    "status" : "A",
    "price" : 25,
    "items" : [{
        "sku" : "ggg",
        "qty" : 7,
        "price" : 2.5
      }, {
        "sku" : "ppp",
        "qty" : 5,
        "price" : 2.5
      }]
  }
}, this is the output, but it also contains "{
        "sku" : "ppp",
        "qty" : 5,
        "price" : 2.5
      }" inside "items", which do not match our criteria.

Comment: Copy my code and paste it to mongo console. I just tried it and it works fine.

Comment: > db.runCommand({
...   mapreduce: 'orders',
...   query: {
...     items: {
...       $elemMatch: {
...         qty: {$gt: 5},
...         sku: 'ggg'
...       }
...     }
...   },
...   map: function map (){
...     this.items = this.items.filter(function (entry) {
...       return (entry.qty>5 && entry.sku=='ggg')
...     });
...     emit(this._id,this);
...   },
...   reduce: function reduce (key, values) {
...     return values[0];
...   },
...   verbose: true,
...   out: {
...     merge: 'map_reduce'
...   }
... })

Comment: result i gt:{
        "result" : "map_reduce",
        "timeMillis" : 51,
        "timing" : {
                "mapTime" : 3,
                "emitLoop" : 49,
                "reduceTime" : 0,
                "mode" : "mixed",
                "total" : 51
        },
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 1,
                "emit" : 1,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 1
        },
        "ok" : 1
}

Comment: Actual output in "map_reduce":{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "value" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
    "cust_id" : "abc123",
    "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
    "status" : "A",
    "price" : 25,
    "items" : [{
        "sku" : "ggg",
        "qty" : 7,
        "price" : 2.5
      }, {
        "sku" : "ppp",
        "qty" : 5,
        "price" : 2.5
      }]
  }
}

Comment: What version of `mongodb` are you using? It works fine in `Mongo v2.4.5` on my Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll try it on my Windows PC when I'll be near it. Try to play with `map` function to ensure that `items` is filtered. For example, you may try to create new `var doc = this` first. I don't think I'll be able to provide further help to you unless I'll find Windows PC.

Comment: Ok but I am using 2.4.1, but data is inconsistent,in windows please verify once if you get the same we need to inform the mongodb team.

Comment: Tested it with `Mongo 2.0.4` on my windows PC, everything worked fine.

Comment: Tested with `Mongo 2.4.5` on windows, everything is fine.

Comment: I tried again, by restarting mongod, but it dosen't come on windows. I am using windows 7,mongo 2.4.3